# Bash - changing rights to apache's log file

Tags: php, apache, bash

I want to allow some users in system to read apache's error.log file.

This is what I did:

At first I tried to change group's owner of error.log file by assigning it to group belonging to the current user. This didn't help. So I decided to do it more direct way.

I set me as owner of apache's log file.
This is what I got:

[image]

Oh, and I can't do "ls" without sudo too.
I can't grasp the problem. I am the owner of this file and I want to cat it.

What's wrong with this?

UPDATES:

Upper directory:

[image]

Permissions of Apache2 directory in /var/log/apache2:

[image]

Comment: Do you own the parent directory?

Comment: updated. no. if I need to give user access to the whole directory then this approach for allowing users to see log files seems to be completely wrong.. Just only one file would be enough

Comment: What are the permissions on the apache2 folder?

Comment: Updated. How could it be relevant at all what kind of rights it has? Logs are stored anyway in another folder, not in /etc/ directory

Comment: Sorry, I meant /var/log/apache2

Comment: I'm pretty sure he was asking the permissions of /var/log/apache2, not of /etc/apache2. The permissions of that folder would be relevant.

Comment: Updated. ok, I'm sorry for my misunderstanding. That's strange that it has "adm" as group's owner. I didn't create any "adm" users/groups....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To view logs, you need to be in the adm group.

sudo usermod -G adm shb

https://superuser.com/questions/86347/whats-difference-between-group-admin-and-adm

Comment: Or add `r-x` to `apache2`, `chmod o+rx apache2`

Comment: Yes, you could change the folder permissions too but I personally would avoid changing system folder permissions.

Comment: perhaps -a option should be added, so command would look as sudo usermod -a -G adm shb